# Does it make any difference if I filter out the records that will not be changed in an update?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, sql-update

Apologies if this question has been asked, I couldn't find it.

I have a situation where I have to update a few records based on a condition, my question is if it makes any difference for the DB to filter out the records that are already with the value I am going to set.

For example, given the following table:

```
+------+-------+----------+
| Id   | Status| Category |
+------+-------+----------+
| 1    | 1     | 1        |
| 2    | 1     | 1        |
| 3    | 1     | 1        |
| 4    | 1     | 2        |
| 5    | 0     | 2        |
| 6    | 0     | 2        |
| 7    | 1     | 2        |
+------+-------+----------+
```

I want to set `status = 0 WHERE Category = 2`, and since I already have a couple that `status = 0` I wonder if there's any difference somewhere if my query is:

`UPDATE table SET status = 0 WHERE category = 2`

or

`UPDATE table SET status = 0 WHERE category = 2 AND Status != 0`

Any comments are hugely appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: 'If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html - or was the question about performance?

Comment: the result will be the same, but adding the extra criteria can help performance in most RDBMS.  It's not a bad practise to not select what doesn't need an update.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, the question is more about performance

Comment: @LukStorms I know, the question is more about the depths of the engine, will it actually help the performance or do you think it will?

Comment: Haven't tested it on MySql. And it can depend on other stuff, like size of table, the query optimizer. Just run both queries again and see if it matters.

Comment: Btw, the 2nd query won't update those with a NULL status.  I was assuming it's a non-nullable field.

Comment: yes, I know @LukStorms, I want to know if the engine behaves differently, if internally this filter is applied anyway or anything like that

Comment: Don't know. And it might depend on the version of MySql. To test it I suppose a trigger would be needed to check if the first update changes everything or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `INDEX(category, Status)` (in that order), it probably does run faster.  This is because the index is "covering", but only in that it can decide which rows are interesting entirely from the `INDEX`.  When it finds a row to change, it still has to fetch, update, and store the row.

Without that index, it will have to fetch the row to check both columns.  At that point, there is not much to do before deciding that the row does not need updating, and moving on.

It turns out that the most costly part of an `UPDATE` is saving the old value of the row in case there is a server crash row a deliberate `ROLLBACK`.  If you are *changing* (not just *checking*) a million row, the `UPDATE` will be painfully slow.

Hence, I *expect* the existence of that "composite, covering" index is only a minor part of the entire time taken.

(I agree that `NULL` values can lead to surprises.)

(My suggested index is more likely to apply to InnoDB.  MyISAM is quite old and not well maintained; I hesitate to predict its action.)